# X-Cart - SQL error notification (Error code : 1030)

Tags: sql, x-cart

I am working on xcart website for my company. Right now, I always get the error messages from my website http://mothersenvogue.com.kh/ as below:

```
[24-May-2015 08:50:51] (shop: 24-May-2015 15:50:51) SQL error:
   Site        : https://mothersenvogue.com.kh
   Remote IP   : 176.9.29.209
   Logged as   :
   SQL query   : SHOW FIELDS FROM xcart_session_history
   Error code  : 103
   Description : Got error 28 from storage engine
Request URI: /secure_login.php?xid=025530538a738ddc86617a9aa81bc990
Backtrace:
/home/www/mothersenvogue.com.kh/include/func/func.db.php:189
/home/www/mothersenvogue.com.kh/include/func/func.db.php:115
/home/www/mothersenvogue.com.kh/include/func/func.db.php:384
/home/www/mothersenvogue.com.kh/include/func/func.db.php:630
/home/www/mothersenvogue.com.kh/include/func/func.db.php:458
/home/www/mothersenvogue.com.kh/include/sessions.php:161
/home/www/mothersenvogue.com.kh/init.php:524
/home/www/mothersenvogue.com.kh/preauth.php:51
/home/www/mothersenvogue.com.kh/auth.php:45
/home/www/mothersenvogue.com.kh/secure_login.php:37
-------------------------------------------------
```

Many error messages are from func.db.php, init.php, preauth.php, auth.php all at the same line number, and on the same SQL Query "SHOW" statement.
I tried to check all the above files at their given line number but I could not find anything wrong.
Pleasse kindly help advise me what is wrong with it? is it something wrong inside these files as I got many error messages sent to me by email with the similar content like above.
I was refered to here from my previous question in xcart forum, and here is my question there:
https://bt.x-cart.com/view.php?id=44717

Many thanks.

Comment: Mysql error "28 from storage engine" - means "not enough disk space". It can also occur when the  /tmp filesystem reaches 100% of usage.

Comment: Thanks Jaco. I wonder how can i check my space in x-cart? Now, my website is hosting in www.xynadoo.com. I use an unlimited storage plan why it says not enough disk space?.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases the file storage (the drive where your files are located on the hosting server, where you checked the free space) is physically located on a different virtual / physical server / drive. Most hosting companies use an optimized dedicated servers for MySQL. 
Thus you see enough space in your account, but MySQL still reports that there is no space left on the drive (where MySQL server is currently running).

Thus the best way is to contact the hosting provider and find out what's the situation with the disk space on that very machine, where MySQL is running.